# Consume messages from multiple dynamic keys of an exchange

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

We have a microservice which receives messages in random order, this service is in charge of orchestrating these messages and putting into rabbitmq in order. Let's say an example type looks like

```
{
  "type": "Orange",
  "sequence": 4
}
```

The purpose of this service is to filter our messages by type and push messages into rabbitmq in the sequence order. So if the first message received by the service is of type "Mango" with a sequence of "2", it will WAIT until it gets "Mango" with the sequence "1" to push first and will THEN push in "2".

So currently I am using a direct exchange with the routing key as "type" (which from my understanding creates a sort of queue PER type automatically within rabbitmq). Due to the service, they are pushed in the order of the "sequence". The routing key is also dynamic and a new type can be added at any time.

Now currently what I am planning is to have a service which **subscribes to all of these queues** from the direct exchange (e.g.: Apple, Orange, etc queues). This service will be scaled up (clustered). Let's say that the "Apple" queue has 17 messages in it. Then one service instance receives a message of type "Apple" at the end of the queue when this happens no other service should be able to receive the next message of "Apple" until the queue gets an ack for the message when it is done the processing. **So only one message per type should be processed at a time by any service instance** until the queue gets an ack for the current message. However, any multiple types can be processed in parallel as there can be lots of types (even by the same service on multiple threads).

How would I program my consumers to read from the direct exchange in this way, also currently I am unable to write a consumer to read messages from ALL routing keys as a first step?

I am using Spring to communicate with rabbitmq, specifying the key explicitly worked but we want to receive messages from all keys.

An example of what we want is

```
@Bean
public Binding binding1b(DirectExchange direct, Queue autoDeleteQueue1) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(autoDeleteQueue1).to(direct).with("*");
}
```

Also additionally are their concerns about having lots of routing keys which are dynamic, there can be potentially let's say 1000+ keys since the number of keys grows as the application grows.

Answer (score 0):

> which from my understanding creates a sort of queue PER type automatically within rabbitmq

That's not correct. You have to create all those queues and then bind them to the exchange. Right, here already you can use a `routingKey` for binding between exchange and queue. You need to keep in mind that the `routingKey` works only on the broker side, where it decides in the exchange to where to deliver a message.

> So only one message per type should be processed at a time by any service instance

That is indeed a purpose of the queue abstraction: only one consumer gets one message to process. However if you don't want to process messages from the same queue in parallel, you should consider to use `exclusive consumer`.

> How would I program my consumers to read from the direct exchange

You don't read messages from the exchange. That is queue responsibility. You definitely have to declare all the queues before consuming them. One `ListenerContainer` indeed can read from many queues. You even can add queues to consumer to the container at runtime. But in this case you may loose the concurrency feature if you use a single exclusive consumer for all the queue.

> specifying the key explicitly worked but we want to receive messages from all keys.

The `routingKey` is the matter of binding. There is nothing about consuming. Although you can get such a header in the message `amqp_receivedRoutingKey` to filter on the client side. However I'm not sure how that can help here.

I think you need to study more how AMQP protocol works and re-think your architecture and expectations a bit. I don't have a solution in mind right now for you, but should I?..